# how to replace null to 'null' in a python dict

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary

This might be a silly question. I would like to replace from null to 'null' in a dict in python.

```
mydict = {"headers": {"ai5": "8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07", "debug": null, "random": **null**, "sdkv": "7.6"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1462759195259"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906", "game_id": "55107008"}}
```

I can't do any string operation in python as it throws error:

```
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

I have a huge file of 18000 this type of data, and I can't do it manually.

Please help.

Comment: You cannot define `mydict` as a dictionary like that because there is no `null` in Python (that's why you get the "_'null' is not defined_" syntax error). It should be `None`. Perhaps you got that _data_ as a string?

Comment: Are these values stored in a file?? Because this declaration will not work in python. Can you tell the deatils of the format in which you have the values

Comment: I am not defining it. I have a txt file which has 18000 line like this one. and i need to replace all the null to 'null'

Comment: @AshishGhodake i have txt file, which has lots of lines like below : {"headers": {"ai5": "8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07", "debug": null, "random": null, "sdkv": "7.6"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1462759195259"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906", "game_id": "55107008"}}
In which i need to convert all the null to 'null'

Comment: @GauravPhagre That is JSON: ***parse JSON as JSON*** ([Python has built-in support for parsing JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).. the null will be parsed as None, the Python equivalent, in the resulting parsed objects). It is probably less ideal to attempt and copy-paste the JSON "as Python".

Comment: Because you posted code for `mydict={ ... }` with that JSON, it seemed you were trying to define it as a dictionary. How are you reading the data from the text file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want a `"null"` string? If you parse the data properly as JSON (as mentioned by @user2864740), [`null` automatically gets converted to `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder), which is much better for doing whatever else you need to do in your Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to replace anything. Just load the file and  convert the data to dict.

```
import json
import pprint

with open('x.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    pprint.pprint(data)
```

Input (x.json)

```
{
  "headers": {
    "ai5": "8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07",
    "debug": null,
    "random": null,
    "sdkv": "7.6"
  },
  "post": {
    "event": "ggstart",
    "ts": "1462759195259"
  },
  "params": {},
  "bottle": {
    "timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906",
    "game_id": "55107008"
  }
}
```

Output

```
{'bottle': {'game_id': '55107008', 'timestamp': '2016-05-09 02:00:00.004906'},
 'headers': {'ai5': '8fa683e59c02c04cb781ac689686db07',
             'debug': None,
             'random': None,
             'sdkv': '7.6'},
 'params': {},
 'post': {'event': 'ggstart', 'ts': '1462759195259'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. It replaces every **null** with **'null'** and stores it into new file.
 Storing it into same file or writing it to new file and then replacing it with original one is upto you.

```
import re
f_handle = open("test.txt","r+")
f_2 = open("result.txt","w+")
for f_string in f_handle.readlines():
    print(f_string)
    f_result = re.sub(r'(?:^|\W)null(?:$|\W)',"'null'",f_string)
    print(f_result)
    f_2.write(f_result)
f_handle.close()
f_2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
x = json.loads(mydict)
```

and then `null` in your dict will change to be `""`.